# Use react-admin skeleton based on isFetching not isLoading

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to apply this concept on my list page but isFetching is not working as expected it keeps toggeling from true to false

```
 const listContext = useListController();
  const { isFetching, isLoading } = listContext;
    {isFetching ? (
                  <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width={210} height={118} />
                ) : (
                  <List
                    {...props}
                    filters={PostFilter}
                    actions={<ListActions listFilter={PostFilter} />}
                    sx={ListStyles}
                  >
                    <Datagrid>
          ...
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to come from the code you pasted. Could you provide a link to a CodeSandbox reproducing the issue?

Comment: It works Only when i used
{isFetching ? (
                  <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width={210} height={118} />
                ) : (
<ListContextProvider
            value={listContext}
            {...props}
          >
but isFetching keeps rendering true on tab switch or in opening and closing inspector or when onkeyPress on filter Input . Would you suggest any thing help in this  ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-rgb-816jyt?file=/src/dealer/list.js   but when use List with is Fetching it keeps toggle from true to false in render time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rendering the List twice... once with `useListController`, and the other with `<List>`. Both fetch the dataprovider.getList, and you should use one or the other.

Try using a sub component of List instead:

```
const ListView = () => {
 const { isFetching } = useListController();
 if (isFetching) {
   return <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width={210} height={118} />;
 }
 return (
    <Datagrid>
      // ...
    </Datagrid>
  );
}

const DealerLists = ({ props }) => (
  <List
    {...props}
    filters={CustomFilter}
    filterDefaultValues={{ status: "ordered" }}
    sort={{ field: "date", order: "DESC" }}
    perPage={25}
  >
    <ListView />
  </List>
);
```

This should be enough on react-admin v4. If you're on react-admin v3, the ListView may have to clone input props to the Datagrid.